# Brew gettext on Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: php, macos, gettext

I installed gettext with brew and the path to gettext is

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.3.1/bin
```

my PHP-Project is located under `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectMine`

The files I want to translate are in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdochs/projectMine/public_html`

When I'm now in the `bin` folder I type

```
./gettext /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectMine/public_html
```

I also tried this one here, but this didn't seem to work either.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.3.1/bin/gettext -n /Applications/PATHTOFOLDER
```

but this results in nothing. What is the exact command to achieve this. I'm new to Mac and Terminal, because I'm normally a Windows user.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it. I navigated to the folder Where I want my php-files getting scanned for language files and typed this into the termina

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.3.1/bin/xgettext -n *.php
```